# Python Custom logger path error depending on the file path it is used in

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, path, pytest

I have a custom logger. It creates a file in Logs folder.
This is part of the code

```
curr_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
log_file_name = '../Logs/log' + curr_time + '.log'
```

I have a Tests folder in which I create test cases and I use logging in those test cases. Everything works fine for the tests that are in Tests folder

The problem arises when I create tests in subfolders under Tests

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

This is my folder hierarchy

> selenium
>
> > POM
> >
> > > Config

> > > Logs

> > > Pages

> > > Tests

> > > Utilities

I assume it is because of the folder path, because when I change '../Logs/log' to '../../Logs/log' the code starts to work for subfolder tests and throws error message for the tests that are in the main Tests folder

This is the custom logger file

```
import inspect
import logging
import logging.config
import time


def custom_logger(log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    logger_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    curr_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    log_file_name = '../Logs/log' + curr_time + '.log'

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name.format(logger_name), mode='a')
    file_handler.setLevel(log_level)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(filename)s:[%(lineno)s] - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                                  datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    return logger
```

Comment: if you want the logs to be relative to the *code* location, why not use `__file__` to build the path?

Comment: Thank you @2e0byo, after some struggle I found a partial solution to my problem. Please see my answer if interested.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue **partially** with this solution

```
curr_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
path = Path(__file__).parent.absolute().joinpath('Logs')
log_file_name = str(path) + '/log' + curr_time + '.log'
```

The problem with this is that it creates logs files under Utilities/Logs (because custom_logger.py is in Utilities folder) while I wanted them to be created in the project root /Logs folder

*os.chdir* didn't help, as depending on which folder the test is running, it would change the directory incorrectly.

I would be happy if anyone could give a better solution, meanwhile, I will use this solution.

Comment: If I have your hierarchy right, why not just `Path(__file__).parent.parent / f"Logs/log{current_time}.log"` ?

Comment: I don't know why or how, but this solved my issue, thank you so much!
`log_file_name = f"{Path(__file__).parent.parent}/Logs/log{current_time}.log"`